# How to check the distribution of the given data

Tags: time-series, estimation

I am working on time series. I have a set of data which I would like to use for estimation. Can some one tell me how to find under what distribution the data I have goes in. I tried plotting using

```
histfit(data) in matlab
```

can some one help.
Thanks

Comment: Is 'histfit' in some package, or do you mean you just typed it in in the hope that such a command might exist somewhere?

Comment: I am using matlab and histfit is a function

Comment: Ah! No wonder I couldn't find it in R. You should probably edit your post or your tags to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no theorem that gives you the appropriate distribution. Selecting a distribution to modelling your data is more like art (this is related to the quote "all models are wrong, but some are useful").

In order to choose an appropriate model you have to consider:

1. What is the support of your data?
2. Are the data continuous or discrete?
3. How do the tails look like?
4. Does your data look symmetric or asymmetric?
5. Are they unimodal?
6. As well as some other considerations specific to your context.

Considering these characteristics, you can choose an appropriate model from the *looooong* catalogue of distributions ([see for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions)).

Another appealing option is to consider nonparametric methods which avoid the step of selecting a model, however they may not work well with small samples. Try for example with this: `plot(density(data))`.

Moreover, in the context of time series (you used the tag but I couldn't spot something related to it in your question), you may be more interested on modelling the evolution of the observations. For instance, using autoregressive models.

Comment: A nice job with a difficult question to answer constructively.

Comment: @Samarithan Thanks for clear description. I am trying to using some regression on the data for travel time prediction.